# Keras model.fit, dimensions must be equal?

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I am a newbie in ML. I have a set of timeseries data with Date and Temp cols., that I want to use for anomaly detection. I used the MinMax scaler on the data and I got an array normal_train_data with shape (200, 0).
Then I used the autoencoder which uses

```
keras.layers.Dense(128, activation ='sigmoid').
```

After that, when I call

```
history = model.fit(normal_train_data, normal_train_data, epochs= 50, batch_size=128, validation_data=(train_data_scaled[:,1:], train_data_scaled[:,1:]) ...)
```

I get the error:

> ValueaError:  Dimensions must be equal but are 128 and 0  with input shapes: [?,128], [?,0].

As far as I understand the input has shape (200,0) and the output(1,128).
Can you help me to fix this error please? Thankyou

I tried to use tf.keras.layers.Flatten() in the encoder part. I am not sure if it's ok to use Dense layer or should I choose another.

Comment: The error is self-explainable. Check your input format and type. What is about (200, 0)!

Comment: @M.Innat Hey, in this case, normal_train_data is a numpy.ndarray with shape(200.0), strides(8,8), itemsize: 8, type: float64.